# Move background image up and down

Tags: jquery, css, transition

I've got a div with background image. How to do this: when you hover on that div, the background image moves 5px up and then 5 pixel down? For example fast up, and slow down.

My code:

CSS

```
<style>
.place {
background:url(../img/place.png) no-repeat 6px 50%;
}
</style>
```

HTML

```
 <div class="place">
    123 Something Street<br/>
    UB5 212 Liverpool
    </div>
```

How to do this with transition? Or jquery?

Comment: tried something like `position:fixed`

Comment: Why change the structure of the page for a simple effect? CSS3 would, I assume, be able to do this. I don't think CSS3 animation of the background is currently widely supported though, so probably requires jQuery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using CSS3

```
.place {
    background:url(http://lorempixel.com/20/20/) no-repeat;
}

div.place:hover {
    animation:myanim 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation:myanim 0.5s;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
}

@keyframes myanim {
    0% {
        background-position:0 0;
    }
    50% {
        background-position:20px 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position:0 0;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes myanim
/* Safari and Chrome */
 {
    0% {
        background-position:0 0;
    }
    50% {
        background-position:20px 0;
    }
    100% {
        background-position:0 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is working, but when it moves down it's not smooth animation at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.animate()` for `background-position` property:

```
    $('div.place').on('hover', function() {
      $(this).animate({
         'background-position-y': '15px'
      }, 500, 'linear');
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try CSS3:

```
   transition: background-position 1s ease;
   -moz-transition: background-position 1s ease; /* Firefox */
   -webkit-transition: background-position 1s ease; /* Safari and Chrome */
```

Comment: Add `div.place:hover` selector

Answer (score 0):

All you need to add is `background-position` style to your div background and do some little jQuery stuff:

1. add to css:

   > background-position: 10px 10px;
2. and to ready of jQuery :

   > $('.place').hover(function(){
   >           $('.place').css('background-position', '10px 5px');
   >           setTimeout(function(){
   >               $('.place').css('background-position', '10px 10px');
   >           }, 2000);
   >       });

[Here is the working example](http://jsfiddle.net/2zfTJ/)

Comment: With those jsfiddles, they take for ever to load, and rarely ever work. Vote 1 to shut down jsfiddels.